# Getting content from an array of type Asset

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift3, contentful

Im trying to figure out a swift code. I am using Contentful and I'm trying to drill down to get some data. When I do a print of the entry I the value below:

```
"appHeroImages": [Contentful.Link.asset(Contentful.Asset)]]
```

How would I get the data from that? Before the migration I had this:

```
let image = (category.fields["appHeroImages"] as! Array<Any>)[0] as? Contentful.Asset
```

Is there something I need to change in that line?

Answer (score 1):

When using the latest version, `0.9.2`, of [contentful.swift](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.swift), extracting an array of links array (and it's first element) from a linking field on an entry would be done in the following way:

```
if let links = category.fields["appHeroImages"] as? [Link], let firstAsset = links.first?.asset {
  print(asset.urlString!) // Don't implicitly unwrap in a real app.
}
```

If you know that all linked values stored at `"appHeroImages"` are of type `Asset` you could also use flatMap to quickly transform the `[Link]` to an `[Asset]`:

```
guard let assets = (category.fields["appHeroImages"] as? [Link])?.flatMap { $0.asset } else { return }
```